Snowflake UDF accept any number of decimal places
I have a UDTF that before today was running fine but I'm now getting a type mismatch:
Create or replace function my_func(x_in number(3, 2)) 
Returns table(
    X_out number(4, 2),
    Y_out number(4, 2)
)
As 
$$
    Select 
        a * x_in,
        b
    From my_table
$$
;

The old value was 0.55, but got changed to 0.50. Now I'm getting a data type mismatch error for an input of type "number(2, 1)".
There's a chance that the input value could go to a 3 decimal point number or down to 1 decimal point as it is now. Is there a way to accept a number with any number of decimal points without having to cast the input to a specific number format or forcing the user to pass a string to my function that I cast from there?

Have you looked into this documentation link?
https://docs.snowflake.com/sql-reference/operators-arithmetic#multiplication
I would just make sure your output numbers are padded enough to handle the largest scale of both the input and the table columns.

I have @MikeWalton, but it doesn't seem to work. The input (0.5) gets coerced to a number(2,1) if I don't cast it to a (3,2) in the function call, and that throws an error even though the function is expecting a (3,2).

Instead of specifying the decimal points, you can use FLOAT data type.
ref

Precision is approximately 15 digits.

Create or replace function my_func(x_in FLOAT) 
Returns table(
    X_out number(4, 2),
    Y_out number(4, 2)
)
As 
$$
    Select 
        a * x_in,
        b
    From my_table
$$
;

eg:


Thanks for this! I considered this as an option as well, however using this solution would require me to either a) change all my output values to FLOAT and then cast them to fixed precision values in a view for my front end, or b) cast every value in my query to a fixed precision number, as the fixed precision is necessary. Less work/processing to just cast the input parameters.
